# Read File automatically from internal memory in android studio?

Tags: android

I want to make a simple application. Something like this:

1. The application can read files in the form of documents (pdf, doc).
2. I provide several file categories in the application including language, mathematics, physics and others.
3. When one of the categories of documents is opened, it will automatically read documents that are on the internal memory.
   Each document will be placed in a folder according to the category
4. When there are new documents that I place on the internal memory according to the folder of the category, it will automatically increase in the application.

Can anyone help me and give a reference?

Comment: That's good that you want it, but you didn't mention any problems you have. What exactly is a problem for you?

Comment: Hey, What is the exact issue?